# Combining First and Last names into a single field

Tags: php

I'm just wondering if there is a less verbose way of expressing this logic. I feel like there should be a one or two line solution using arrays maybe, but I can't think of one. The code should combine first and last name with a space in between (no space if only one of them exist, or leave the field blank if neither exist.

```
if ($formData['fname'] && $formData['lname'])
    $this->_properties['baname'] = $formData['fname'].' '.$formData['lname'];
elseif ($formData['fname'])
    $this->_properties['baname'] = $formData['fname'];
elseif ($formData['lname'])
    $this->_properties['baname'] = $formData['lname'];
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$this->_properties['baname'] = trim($formData['fname'].' '.$formData['lname']);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
    $this->_properties['baname'] = $formData['fname'].
                                  (($formData['fname'] && $formData['lname']) ? 
                                         ' ':'').$formData['lname'];
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$fullName = implode(' ', array($formData['fname'], $formData['lname']));
```